Automatic counter
I´d like to make an automatic counter beside a specific condition. For example, the counter should count the sequence of victories of a team. If the result is win count 1, see another date, if another win count 2 and so on. If the team lose, so the counter must be 0 and start it again next date.
I´ve tried chat GPT but the solution didn´t work at all (maybe I didn´t do properly the prompt )

Can you share some data ?

Hi Amira, that's as simple as that example Pic that I've sent. I'm a newbie in this I don't even know how to start it, it's just an idea

There is no picture in your question

you can also paste the sample data and expected output in the table in your post.
